Error rendering text in rayshader and opactiy also don't work when using render_higquality
The opacity of polygon and text works when using plot_3d only but whenever i use render_highquality, text are replaced by rectangular box with no text and opactity of polygon is always 1 though using only polygon vector the opactity works with any value in plot_3d.
Here is the image

Here both text appears and opacity is also working..and here is output after using render_highquality

here text don't appear and opacity is solid.
Here is the code,


plot_3d(zion_rgb_contrast, zionel_matrix, windowsize = c(1100,600), zscale = 15, shadowdepth = -50,
        zoom=0.6, phi=20,theta=-45,fov=70, background = "#F2E1D0", shadowcolor = "#523E2B")

render_polygons(ktm_sh, 
                extent = attr(elevation_cropped,"extent"),alpha = 0.2, top=90,
                parallel=FALSE,color = "red")

render_polygons(recharge_sh, 
                extent = attr(elevation_cropped,"extent"), alpha = 0.2, top=100,
                parallel=FALSE,color = "chartreuse4")
render_label(zionel_matrix, lat =27.66831,
             long =85.29755, extent=attr(elevation_cropped, "extent"),
             freetype=T, zscale =12,text = "Bagmati",
             dashed = F, textsize = 0.6, linewidth = 2,
             textcolor = "black", linecolor="Darkorange")

render_highquality(
  text_angle = NULL,
  scale_text_size = 6,
  scale_text_offset = c(0, 0, 0),
  text_size = 24,
  override_material = FALSE,
  text_offset = c(0, 0, 0),
  sample_method = "sobol_blue",
  interactive = FALSE,
  line_radius = 1
)



